# Is my evaluation of $\int_{D}\int e^{-{(4x^2+5y^2)}} \; dA$ correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\int_{D}\int e^{-{(4x^2+5y^2)}} \; dA$ where $D :\frac{x^2}{5} +\frac{y^2}{4} \leq 1$

I have used the transformation :

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{(5)}}=u $ and $\frac{y}{2}  =v$

Which yields $|J| = 2\sqrt{5}$

$\int_{D}\int e^{-{(4x^2+5y^2)}} \; dA = \int_{D*}\int e^{-{20(u^2+v^2)}} \; du \; dv$

where $D* : u^2 + v^2 =1$

Further I want to use polar coordinates

$\int_{D*}\int e^{-{20(u^2+v^2)}} \; du \; dv = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{1} \; e^{-20r^2}r \; dr \; d \theta$

The final result I am getting is : $\frac{\sqrt{5}\times(1-e^{-20})\times2\pi}{20}$

And my text book lists $0 $ as the answer.

I don't see how the answer will be $0$. What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of D?

Comment: @gimusi please check again..

Comment: try with wolfy justvto check! And change book !!! :)

Comment: @gimusi is the part till polar coordinates fine? I mean the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \; e^{-(20)r^2} r \; dr \; d \theta$

Comment: It seems ok, a part that |J| is not indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can’t be zero since exponential function is strictly positive!

We can’t exclude there is a typo in the textbook.